# get the two types of sets from a model with condition

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get the credits and debits from the model, with condition tried a lot of methods but failed to approach the answer, the model i am working on is

```
class SupplierTrans(models.Model):
    supplierName = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-update', '-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.supplierName)
    
    @property
    def paid_purchsased(self):
        return 'Paid' if self.paid == True else "Purchased"
```

I approach in a methos that is

```
sup = SupplierTrans.objects.annotate( credit = Sum('amount', paid=True), debit= Sum('amount', paid=False)).order_by('supplierName__name')
```

but its not working the out is get the all the sum of the amount in the table if not filtering boolean values

but the required is getting by the following method

```
credit_amt = SupplierTrans.objects.filter(paid=True).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
debit_amt = SupplierTrans.objects.filter(paid=False).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

I wana get the following values in the above condition is there any approach, or should change the table structure

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to get totals for paid vs unpaid records. The following query should do the job:

```
SupplierTrans.objects.values('paid').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))
```

Related django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values